# Is there any way to define attributes in Sequelize conditionally

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to fetch some attributes of a Model, but one attribute only when a condition satisfies.
Is it possible to achieve this in Sequelize?

Eg. Model

| id | email | mobile | created_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 | 12345 | a |
| 2 | row2 | 12345 | b |
| 3 | row3 | 12345 | a |
| 4 | row4 | 12345 | b |

I want to fetch attributes id, email, mobile when created_by = a
otherwise fetch only attributes id and email.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Nothing, just comments below ↓

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, I think my question was unclear, just updated the question.

Comment: Hi no problems. So I'm note sure if it is possible using sequelize. Maybe you could take a look at raw queries https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditional select a column, but you control whether to select the value or some other value with a `case` expression; for this select null instead. So

```
select id 
     , email
     , case when created_by = 'a' 
            then mobile
            else null
       end  as mobile
  from model;
```

Sorry but I do not know Sequelize, but translating should not be difficult.